# Hive SQL error: Failed rule ‘identifier’ in the Select target

Tags: hadoop, hive, hiveql, hive-query

I wrote a hive sql query here:

```sql
SELECT
 dt,
 COUNT(CASE WHEN search_word like ‘%A%’ THEN id END) AS a,
 COUNT(CASE WHEN search_word like ‘%B%’ THEN id END) AS b,
 FROM database
 GROUP BY dt
```

However, Hive returns an error :

> Error while compiling statement : Failed
> ParseExceptionline 3:7 Failed to recognise predicate ‘AS’. Failed rule: ‘identifier’ in the select target.

I searched this error and my assumption is it might be come from `AS` reserve word. But I still do not understand how to fix it.

Comment: Patterns %A%  should be in quotes: '%A%'

Comment: My original code has '%A%' . Thanks your commentp

Comment: Other possible issues: extra comma after AS b; strange table name 'database'